# Download stuck in Gmail

Tags: gmail, downloading

I had started downloading a attached file from GMail app, suddenly it hang. When it resumed, notification bar was showing download process but it was not being downloaded in the app. i retried and downloaded it. Its been 3 days but notification bar still shows the file is being downloaded. I have tried switching off the phone but doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I should do. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might need to clear the cache of the Download Manager. Go into:

```
Settings -> Apps -> All (tab) -> Download Manager
```

Here tap `Clear cache` and for good measure `Clear data`