# GMail attachment download does not complete

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, gmail, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7, attachments, download-manager

I am using Jelly Bean on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0. I have been trying to download an attachment from the GMail app. All I see is a progress bar which shows 0% progress and an icon added in the notification area. The download does not proceed beyond 0%. I restarted the tablet and the icon is back! But the download stays at 0% and does not progress.

Has anyone else faced this problem? How do I remove the icon from the notification area?

Comment: See: [Download stuck in Gmail](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26670/16575). Not quite the identical problem, but the same solution might apply.

Comment: Glad to read! As suggested, I described the required steps with an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not the identical issue, the solution provided with the question [Download stuck in Gmail](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26670/16575) solves it as well:

Clear the cache of the Download manager. To do so, go to *Settings→Apps→Manage Apps*, switch to the "All" Tab, scroll to the "Download Manager". Tap that entry, and hit the button labeled "Clear Cache". Optionally, also tap "Clear Data", if cache-cleaning alone does not solve the issue.

Comment: "Clear Data" is what did it.

Comment: Not a double meaning, so no pun intended: Thanks for clearification :)

Comment: I had the same problem with 5.1 Lollipop. What fixed it: Clear Cache + Clear Data on both Download Manager & Downloads apps, then reboot phone. I also had strange problems with installing / updating apps (particularly: Dropbox) via Google Play shortly before GMail started to show symptoms. Cleaning up as stated above fixed those, too.